# .position() and .offset returning NULL off my target

Tags: jquery

Im trying to check the position of an element on this page, and if its below a certain point I want to change the font color to something readable, but .position and .offset(which is what I should be using) are both returning NULL.

Here is my jquery, the alert is in there for testing purposes:

```
  var position = $("#about_tattoo").offset();
  alert("top: "+ position.top);
  if(position.top >= 1000){
    $("#about_tattoo").css("color","white");
  }
```

and there is a div on the page: `<div id="about_tattoo">`

Comment: unable to see code block properly...why!!!

Comment: Check if the elelment exists in the DOM

Comment: Are you sure your `#about_tattoo` is(:visible). Try `alert($("#about_tattoo").is(":visible"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its working here

http://jsfiddle.net/smd8b/

make sure you have wrapped the code in

```
$(function(){
...
});
```